# How to remove adornments like [exec] when using groovy's AntBuilder

Tags: shell, ant, groovy, exec

I'm using Groovy's AntBuilder to execute Ant tasks:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sequential {
    ant.exec(executable: "cmd", dir: "..", resultproperty: "exec-ret-code") {
        arg(value: "/c")
        arg(line: "dir")
    }
}
```

The output lines are prefixed by:

[exec]

Using Ant on the command line, this is turned off by "emacs mode"

```
ant -emacs ...
```

Is there a way to switch to emacs mode using AntBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no general way to add command-line arguments to the AntBuilder execution, but there's a way to activate the emacs mode, although it's not that pretty:

```
logger = ant.project.buildListeners.find { it instanceof org.apache.tools.ant.DefaultLogger }
logger.emacsMode = true
```

Comment: Just tested and it works! Thanks Christoph!

Groovy guys, please add a groovier way to do this! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is from 2010, but for future searchers this seems to work:

```
ant.project.buildListeners[0].messageOutputLevel=0
```

0 is pretty close to silent (It still listed classes that need building, but got rid of most of the other junk), 3 is quite verbose.